# How to find value max in grouping for each ID in sql b2b

Tags: sql, db2, grouping

I have the following table:

Table1

```
outstanding|month|year|ID
5000000    |07   |2017|1234
4000000    |08   |2017|1234
6000000    |09   |2017|1234
4500000    |10   |2017|1234
500000     |08   |2017|1235
700000     |09   |2017|1235
4500000    |07   |2017|1236
3000000    |08   |2017|1236
4800000    |09   |2017|1236
4500000    |10   |2017|1236
```

I want to achieve the result which selects all field on TABLE1 and new column is MAX_OUTSTANDING. the MAX_OUTSTANDING column will be filled with the maximum value of the OUTSTANDING column per ID. Ie:

```
OUTSTANDING|MONTH|YEAR|ID  |MAX_OUSTANDING
5000000    |07   |2017|1234|6000000
4000000    |08   |2017|1234|6000000
6000000    |09   |2017|1234|6000000
4500000    |10   |2017|1234|6000000
500000     |08   |2017|1235|700000
700000     |09   |2017|1235|700000
4500000    |07   |2017|1236|4800000
3000000    |08   |2017|1236|4800000
4800000    |09   |2017|1236|4800000
4500000    |10   |2017|1236|4800000
```

Can someone help with the query? Thank you before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a window function:

```
select t.*,
       max(outstanding) over (partition by id) as max_outstanding
from table1 t;
```

The window function is pretty much a direct translation of your description.

Comment: I guess you are missing Order by clause in window function.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai No, he's not missing it, because we want the max over each partition.  There is no concept of "order" in this case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, What I have read is Order By clause is must clause while working with window function. Is it not correct every time?

Comment: No, it's not correct.  If `ORDER BY` be omitted, then I believe the window defaults to  all records inside that partition.  So, in the case of `MAX` in Gordon's answer, it means take the max of all records in that partition.

Comment: Thank you very much @Gordon Linoff your script is working and with the result as expected.